# How to select meta value column based on user id and two meta keys

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, phpmyadmin

I want to select values 'b' and 'c' by meta key and user id = 197

[image: select issue]

```
Select cc.meta_value, fname,cc.meta_value lname FROM usermeta cc where 
user_id = 197 and (cc.meta_key = 'last_name' or cc.meta_key = 'first_name')
```

Comment: can you add more details on the logic

Comment: do you need `b` & `c` as records or as columns?

Comment: Those are values and I need both of them. @Moulitharan M

Answer (score 1):

You could use the second condition in the `WHERE clause` to achieve what you want. It's important to wrap the second condition inside parentheses. Like this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM wp_usermeta 
WHERE user_id = 1 
AND 
(
CONVERT(meta_key USING utf8) = 'first_name' 
OR
CONVERT(meta_key USING utf8) = 'last_name'
)
```

Which outputs this:

[image]

---

If you only need the `meta_value` column, then you could use this:

```sql
SELECT meta_value 
FROM wp_usermeta 
WHERE user_id = 1 
AND 
(
CONVERT(meta_key USING utf8) = 'first_name' 
OR
CONVERT(meta_key USING utf8) = 'last_name'
)
```

Which outputs this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If You want to select them in one query:

```
select meta_value from YOURTABLENAME where user_id=197 
and meta_key in ('first_name','last_name')
```

Or if You want to select them separately:

```
select meta_value from YOURTABLENAME where user_id=197 and meta_key='last_name';
select meta_value from YOURTABLENAME where user_id=197 and meta_key='first_name';
```

Comment: It didn't work and just return "first_name". I need theme in one query.

Comment: This mean than You "see" not the same value You read from screen. it may be " last_name" or "last_name ". Update Your meta key like this 
`update YOURTABLENAME set meta_key='last_name' where user_id=197 and meta_value='c'`
and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> `In` will get you all the values in the specified list

```
Select cc.meta_value fname,cc.meta_value lname 
FROM usermeta cc where 
user_id = 197 and cc.meta_key in('last_name','first_name')
```

Comment: It didn't work and just return "last_name"